# Use of sendmail as input mail gateway with Google G Suite

Tags: email, gmail, smtp, sendmail

I'm attempting to use Google G Suite to host *some* email addresses but not all.

I currently have a server hosting my domain and the MX server for this domain. There are no local email account, everything is forwarded to other email addresses via virtusertable.

What I'd like is for the MX entry to remain the same, but the mail to joe@domain.com be forwarded to gmail's joe@domain.com address.

G Suite has an entry on how this could be done there:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/60730?hl=en

The most useful description however is "Configure the inbound mail gateway server to deliver mail to the G Suite mail servers.
The configuration steps differ depending on the gateway server."

So I'd like to do this with sendmail (sorry all habits, I've been carrying that config for close to two decades, and I can't be bothered learning another MTA)

Something like in the virtusertable like:
joe@domain.com   MX:joe@domain.com@GOOGLE_SMTP_SERVER_IP

Any ideas on how this could be done, and if it can be done with sendmail?

thank you

Comment: You want to forward messages addressed `joe@domain.com` to GOOGLE_SMTP_SERVER_IP without changing envelope recipient (`RCPT TO:` in SMTP session), don't you?

Comment: That's exacly right. The G sync recipient address being the same as the one the MX entry getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Sendmail: Redirect SOME addresses in the domain to another host without changing envelope recipient

You may use `FEATURE(ldap_routing)`.
It may be used without ldap lookups.  It can use standard sendmail maps (hash/btree/...) instead.

`sendmail.mc` fixes (compile it into `sendmail.cf` and restart or HUP sendmail daemon):

```
LDAPROUTE_DOMAIN(`example.com')dnl
FEATURE(`ldap_routing',`hash /etc/mail/mailhost',`null')dnl
```

`null` map returns always "not found" - I have used as map rewriting recipient address

`/etc/mail/mailhost` file (requires compilation with `makemap hash mailhost`):

```
joe@example.com  [GOOGLE_SMTP_SERVER_IP]
```

`[]` around IP address turn off lokkup for MX records.

---

## Testing

It should be conducted by root in typical sendmail installation.

```
# check where sendmail would deliver emails for joe@example.com 
sendmail -bv joe@example.com
# as above but with tracking map lookups including mailhost map
sendmail -d60.5 -bv joe@example.com
# worst case debug procedure - tracking R lines processing in sendmail.cf
echo '3,0 joe@example.com' | sendmail -d60.5 -d21.12 -bt
```

Comment: Absolutely awesome. Worked first go. I owe you a beer !